# [Solved]Windows 10 stuck at Windows 10 Logo at boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, virtualbox, windows-update

I have a Virtual Box running Windows 10, every time a bigger Update is installed at the shutdown, the next time I start the Virtual Box Windows 10 gets stuck at the Windows 10 Logo.

I have the VirtualBox version 5.0.36 r114008 running on Debian.

Am I the only person having this problem? Because I can't find something at the Internet about that...

Comment: Did you set enough RAM and video memory for that VM? Is HDD set to dynamically expanding?

Comment: @Biswa The Virtual Maschine got 4GB of the installed 8GB from the Host, and the the HDD is not dynamically expanding but with 900GB it should be big enough. And if it helps the Host is an dual boot with Debian and Windows 10, but the Windows 10 is also virtualized in Virtualbox on Debian..

Comment: Now I've got it running, I just had to start Windows 10 from the hard drive and not in Virtualbox what is running on Linux... But thank anyway.